# Phonegap - Pages from subfolder not loading

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, directory, hyperlink

I'm developing a web app with jQuery Mobile, which works great. Now I'd like to make a native app using Phonegap.

In the web app, the links were like this : /subfolder/page.html

The javascripts, CSS, and other linked pages weren't loading in the native app, so I changed all my links by subfolder/page.html

Now the scripts, CSS and linked pages from index.html work. But when I am on a page within a subfolder (I accessed the page via index.html), the linked pages don't load. jQuery Mobile shows a pop-up saying "Error loading page". But my links aren't broken...

```
<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b"><a href="Chirurgie_de_l'obésité/Principes.html" data-transition="slide">Principes</a></li>
```

This link will work in index.html, but not in any other other pages from a subfolder.

I think the problem comes from the ajax-based navigation...

Thank you in advance for your help,
Adrien B.

Comment: Do you have several html pages in your subfolder or just one html page with several jQuery Mobile pages inside?

Comment: Several html pages! Thanks for caring about my problem!

Comment: Ok, lets go even further, when you go from your first subfolder page to your second subfolder page what link are you suing. Basically I want to know are you using <a href="...">Some link</a> or change page function. And can you just add this as an example to your question. We will find you a solution in a no time.

Comment: I added the example! And there's nothing in my js about the links.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and please tell me if it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's your problem:

```
<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b"><a href="Chirurgie_de_l'obésité/Principes.html" data-transition="slide">Principes</a></li>
```

If you are connecting two pages inside a same directory you only need to point directly to your html file, you dont need to use sub directory name again.

This must work:

```
<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b"><a href="Principes.html" data-transition="slide">Principes</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying this in a few minutes. But what happens if the linked page is in a different folder? folder1/page1 has a link pointing to folder2/page2 ?

Comment: When you are linking pages you need to look from a perspective of currently active page. For example if you want to access page from a parent directory you would use something like this: href="../index.html"

Answer (score 0):

You can want to add `rel=external` to your `<a/>`s which handle the redirection. But this way you'll end up losing transition provided by jQM. To bypass this, you'd have to use a single page template.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Transitions are very useful in my project, don't you have another solution? Because links are working, but only in the index page!